# After update to Visual Studio 2022 then back to 2019. Root Unity Project folder fills up with VS Project files

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-ndk, virtual-reality, quest

I was prompted to install an update of in the unity hub from 2022.1.20f1 to 2022.2.22f1. During the process of the update VS2019 was updated to 2022.
It broke my code. So I down graded back to the old versions.
Now when the project loads. the Root folder of the project is filled with a massive number of project files. I just don't understand why this is so. I've done full re-installs Unity and VS2019 after a complete uninstall. Having spent a whole day I am lost. Any help would be welcome.

Oh and I am also now missing the NDK so it won't compile for the Quest 2, that's another issue!

[image: Folder Snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

First commit and push all the changes to the remote repository or just make a backup.

1. Since the project is under git control, if possible check out an old branch or clone a new one.
2. If solution 1 is not available, delete the following folders and files, then open the project with Unity.

   - Library
   - Temp
   - *.csproj
   - *.sln

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick response. I had tried that. But still failed.
Then I found the issue
under Edit->Preferences I had the Registry Packages Ticked

Now for the:

```
Android SDK Build-tools component is not found. Make sure all tools are installed in the SDK manager. Latest supported build-tools version is 30.0.3
```